# eclipse removes -javaagent as vm argument

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, javaagents, google-plugin-eclipse

I want to edit the vm arguments of a Spring project in eclipse. The default vm arguments are:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx512m
```

Then I want to add a javaagent arg like this:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx512m -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}\org\springframework\spring-instrument\${org.springframework.version}\spring-instrument-${org.springframework.version}.jar
```

I added the necessary variables.
I click Apply (everything is still OK)
Then I click OK and this closes the dialog. But when I reopen the same run configuration, the -javaagent arg has dissapeared...
and the old config of

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx512m
```

is back.
Can anyone explain me what's going on? I'm using Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 with some maven and spring plugins and the configuration is for a GWT project.

GWT Version: 2.5

Google plugin Version: 3.1.3

Eclipse Version: 4.2.1

Maybe downgrading one of these could help, any ideas?

Comment: Further investigation tells me this has somethings to do with the google-plugin in eclipse

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the google plugin: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4122 You can edit the config file of eclipse by yourself and set the file read only afterwards. But even then if you open the configuration the -javaagent arg is missing and if you run the project, it returns an error the -javaagent arg is not set... The proposed solution there doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you tried to export your launch config and set it to readonly as well?

Comment: Looks like that issue should be filed against the GPE instead of GAE. The GPE issue tracker is here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/list